# changed by the database link to a section of a store developed with Magento

Tags: magento

Now that i've made ​​some progress in my study  about the structure of Magento  I think I can explain better the same question I posted two days ago.

Does anyone know where (in the database) are the destination links to a Magento store categories?

http://peluches-cel.com 
Peluche del mes section ----------------->I want the destination of this section changes to a new url

many thanks!!!!!!! to all that you strive to understand my "English Hispanicized"

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but this can change since backend of Magento. 
[image]

This solve your question?